# jquery ajaxSubmit: how to optionally load response page

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that elicits various responses; it expects a certain format of response (and will get it under normal conditions), but if the server gets an error or otherwise redirects, I need to handle the page that gets returned by replacing the DOM with that page. In other words, I EITHER want to act like a normal form submission (which replaces the page) or get my special data.

The key, of course, is jQuery's ajaxSubmit, which gets the result of a form WITHOUT loading the page. So, having interrupted the normal forms processing and gotten this error page in hand, how do I then have it take over the browser?

At the level of the $.submit function I can return true to prevent normal handling. How can ajaxSubmit's success function "resume" it?

Answer (score 0):

If you submit with Ajax, you can't then "re-activate" the non-Ajax form processing. What you can do is, if you are getting an entire page back through the Ajax call and you want to replace the page with that page, is use Javascript and DOM to replace the entire page. If for instance your returned content has a body tag in it, you can replace the current body tag with the new one. This is not exactly the same as forwarding the browser to the new page but it has the same effect.